# Use of .sa_sigaction and .sa_handler in same project(man page clarification)

Tags: linux, signals, manpage, sigaction

While looking up the man pages for sigaction, I stumbled upon a confusing note in the Linux man pages:

> On some architectures a union is involved: do not assign to both
>   sa_handler and sa_sigaction([sigaction man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)).

There are two possible ways to read it:

1. Does this mean, as I understand it, that you are not allowed to set `.sa_sigaction` and `.sa_handler` in the same `struct sigaction`.
2. Or is one only allowed to use either `.sa_sigaction` OR `.sa_handler` in the whole project?

```c
struct sigaction sigactionArray[SIGNAL_SIGACTION_ARRAY_SIZE] = {
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_handler = SIG_DFL, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER},
   {.sa_sigaction = HandleBacktraceSignals, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK}
};
```

According to interpretation 1. the above piece of code would be fine, but when definition 2. is right, it would be invalid since I mix.

Which one is true?
Note: On my architecture, it is defined as a union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just talking about the same structure. It explains why: they might be part of a `union`, so they use the same memory in the structure. E.g. it might actually be like:

```
struct sigaction {
    union {
        void     (*sa_handler)(int);
        void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    },
    sigset_t   sa_mask;
    int        sa_flags;
    void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

Therefore, writing to one of them overwrites the other.